# MySQL - сортировка от самого большого

Tags: php, mysql, select

Есть допустим такие значения в бд:

```
id float
1  2.1
2  3.3
3  33.4
4  7.5
5  78.3
6  90.3
```

Если я сделаю запрос к mysql:
`SELECT float FROM hours ORDER BY float DESC`

То выведет в таком порядке:
`90.3 78.3 7.5 33.4 3.3 2.1`

Но мне нужно чтобы было в таком порядке:
`90.3 78.3 33.4 7.5 3.3 2.1`

Comment: Сомневаюсь что mysql не умеет сортировать. Точно тип поля float (decimal\double)? А не text\varchar?

Comment: Преобразуйте поле с именем `float` и типом данных, видимо, `VARCHAR`, в тип `FLOAT` (или `DECIMAL`). Временно - можно пользоваться ```ORDER BY `float` + 0 DESC```.

Comment: Akina, u_mulder, у меня стоит тип поля char(34)

Comment: если у вас число, то храните его как число, не надо хранить числа в виде строк и пытаться их сортировать.

Comment: с каких пор, char - это строка? Я больше поверю, что мне надо тип числа перевести в float

Comment: Да, ребята, вы были правы, надо было поставить в тип `FLOAT`, у меня было `char`, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akina, u_mulder, большое спасибо, установил тип столбца float (был char), теперь работает!

Comment: является.......

Comment: Напишите ответ чтоб было полезно и остальным

Comment: я написал, что установил тип столбца float, этого мало?

Comment: я сделал вышеуказанное действие, у меня всё работает, че еще писать